# NG-ZORRO 'nz-list-item-meta-title' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

i installed NG-ZORRO to use it on my project and i begin by using their list component.

but i am getting errors on elements like : 
'nz-list-item-meta-title' is not a known element
 and nz-list-item-action is not a known element

i imported all modules that requires using list but always have the same error.

this `nz-list-item-meta-title` just doesn't exist...
here is mu app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgZorroAntdModule, NZ_I18N, fr_FR } from 'ng-zorro-antd';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import fr from '@angular/common/locales/fr'
import { CollectionProgressComponent } from './collection-progress/collection- 
progress.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { TvComponent } from './tv/tv.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { InConstructionComponent } from './in-construction/in-construction.component';
import { DonationComponent } from './donation/donation.component';
import { NzListModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/list';
import { PostComponent } from './post/post.component';

registerLocaleData(fr);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CollectionProgressComponent,
    TvComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    InConstructionComponent,
    DonationComponent,
    PostComponent
   ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgZorroAntdModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NzListModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: fr_FR }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you post your routing ... then the html of the component where you use it ... and are you sure the module of your component is the AppModule ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <nz-list nzItemLayout="horizontal">
          <nz-list-item>
            <nz-list-item-meta
              nzAvatar="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png"
              nzDescription="Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team"
              nzTitle="put title here"
            >  
            </nz-list-item-meta>
          </nz-list-item>
        </nz-list>
```

using '`nzTitle`' property to replace '`nz-list-item-meta-title`'

Comment: And `nz-list-item-meta-title` this feature is only for version 9.1.2.